# Streamlined deployment of an Angular/Ionic application to Docker

Tags: angular, docker, ionic-framework

We have a medium sized Angular/Ionic application that takes about 12 minutes to build/deploy to a Docker image on AWS being deployed by `CloudFormation`.  I'd like to see about improving that timeline.

- resolving packages  47 seconds
- fetching packages  24 seconds
- linking dependencies  48 seconds
- Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading  7mins 7 seconds

For the ES5 bundles we have the following browserslist: :

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

Can we somehow cache/remember the build results in some kind of results cache or image - and maybe only occasionally update them maybe by a manual command line or build switch?